# Display notifications over activity when app is starting

Tags: java, android, notifications

At this moment i use push notifications in my app. when i start my app they go into the notification drawer like this 
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9u6U4.png)

but i need them to be over the main activity. i cant find the solution anywhere... Which type of notifications can i use ?(without losing the functionality) and how to dublicate the info from push notifications into that type? also is there a way to display push notifications on the whole screen ? fullscreen ? thats what i want: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9arN.jpg)

Can someone give me a solution and its code as an example?

my code:

```
private static int sNotificationId = 1;
public static int showsId = -1;
```

...

```
         Utils.GetAuthToken(this);
    Bundle intent_extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    showsId = -1;
    if (intent_extras != null && intent_extras.containsKey("com.example.romanchuk.appisode.show_id")) {
        if (intent_extras.containsKey("com.example.romanchuk.appisode.notifyId")) {
            int notification_id = intent_extras.getInt("com.example.romanchuk.appisode.notifyId", -1);
            new ReadNotification(notification_id).execute();

        }
        showsId = intent_extras.getInt("com.example.romanchuk.appisode.show_id", -1);
    } else {
        try {
            ArrayList<NotificationItem> list = new LoadNotifications().execute().get();
            for (int jIndex = 0; jIndex < list.size(); jIndex++) {
                new sendNotification(this, list.get(jIndex).getId(),
                        list.get(jIndex).getShow_id(),
                        list.get(jIndex).getMessage(),
                        "Appisode",
                        list.get(jIndex).getImage()).execute();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

...

```
     private void handleDataMessage(int id, String title, String message) {
    try {
        String imageUrl = "";

        Log.e(TAG, "title: " + title);
        Log.e(TAG, "message: " + message);
        Log.e(TAG, "imageUrl: " + imageUrl);


        if (!true) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

            // play notification sound
            NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
            notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
        } else {
            // app is in background, show the notification in notification tray
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            resultIntent.putExtra("com.example.romanchuk.appisode.notifyId", id);
            resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);

            NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(this);
     //                resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);


              notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, resultIntent);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

private class sendNotification extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    Context ctx;
    int id, show_id;
    String message;
    String title;
    String icon;

    public sendNotification(Context context, int id, int show_id, String message, String title, String icon) {
        super();
        this.ctx = context;
        this.id = id;
        this.show_id = show_id;
        this.message = message;
        this.title = title;
        this.icon = icon;
    }
```

...

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("com.example.romanchuk.appisode.notifyId", id);
        intent.putExtra("com.example.romanchuk.appisode.show_id", show_id);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, sNotificationId , intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

        inboxStyle.addLine(message);

        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigText = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
        bigText.bigText(message);
        bigText.setBigContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx);
        Notification notification = null;

        notification = builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_accent))
                .setContentTitle("Appisode")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setStyle(inboxStyle)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_icon)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri).build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(sNotificationId++, notification);

    }
}
```